# Using django-syncr to create flickr feed

Tags: django

I'd like to put a flickr feed on my homepage using django-syncr; I followed the instructions on the homepage (http://code.google.com/p/django-syncr/), and the installation process was pretty smooth.  Steps 1-3 work just fine, but Step 4 is where I run into problems.

When I try to run the commands shown:

```
from syncr.app.flickr import FlickrSyncr
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_syncr-0.50-py2.7.egg/sync/app/flickr.py", line 11, in <module>
    from syncr.flickr.models import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_syncr-0.50-py2.7.egg/syncr/flickr/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

And I'm not really sure what to do.  These files are run in my django project folder, but including the settings file (via import settings) doesn't seem to fix this.  What files should be included in order to import the right variables?

thanks!

Comment: In step #2 - what did you add to your `PYTHONPATH`? Can you try adding `your_project_name.settings` to the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environmental variable, changing `your_project_name` to match your project name?

Comment: I ran the install script that came with it, so I assumed that it was added to my python path properly.  I can run 'import syncr' in a python terminal and it loads just fine.